# Data disable with is not working - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to disable a button on submit with data-disable-with but I can't seem to get it working on my form.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
  <%= submit_tag "Publish", { class: 'button', data: { disable_with: "Please wait.." } } %>
```

The class is being applied but when I submit the form nothing gets disabled. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: remove the {} that are around "class" and be sure that you have correct html, sometimes a <div> that isn't closed in the right way, can brake those type of things on the forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `button_tag`:

```
<%= button_tag "Publish", class: 'button', data: { disable_with: "Please wait.." } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

tested your button tag with an example and it is working fine

```
<%= form_tag '/', method: :get do %>
  <%= submit_tag "Publish", { class: 'button', data: { disable_with: "Please wait.."} } %>
<% end %>
```

make sure you have `//= require rails-ujs` in application.js file
also can you show more code?

Comment: sorry for type mistake submit_tag*